# Configuring Compass Sinatra to use scss

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sass, compass-sass

I am trying to set up a Sinatra project to use Sass and Compass for the first time. I downloaded the sample app from https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass-sinatra. App.rb is currently configured properly to compile .sass files automatically, but how do I configure it to look for .scss files instead?

```
get '/stylesheets/:name.css' do
  content_type 'text/css', :charset => 'utf-8'
  sass(:"stylesheets/#{params[:name]}", Compass.sass_engine_options )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out to be a simple configuration change from **sass**() to **scss**() in line 3

```
get '/stylesheets/:name.css' do
  content_type 'text/css', :charset => 'utf-8'
  scss(:"stylesheets/#{params[:name]}", Compass.sass_engine_options )
end
```